# How to add Legend Panel to Dojo / OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, legend, dojo, getlegendgraphic

I have OpenLayers app on Dojo framework. I've been serving WMS layers with GeoServer and wanted to use GetLegendGraphic to build legend for all layers.

I've seen there are some ready widgets (like Legend Panel in Esri API or GeoExt) and was wondering is there anything I can easily use with Dojo or OpenLayers?